# I want to download PDF of the page (print preview)

Tags: pdf, printing, download, wordpress

Here is my page (http://apexdemo.hami.net/property/1039-52th-ave-brooklyn-ny-41263/)

I needs to download PDF of the page when I click on "Download Brochure" button under the main picture next to the "Save", "SEND" and "PRINT" buttons. Website is developed in wordpress, is there any plugin available for this functionality.

PDF should be generated of the print preview page instead of the actual page. How to do that (Because there are some changes in actual page and it's print preview page). Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usman, you need to write down custom code for pdfdownload of page. Here I am sharing with you a link which is help for generate a PDF of you page.  I also used "tcpdf" this link for download PDF for wordpress site.

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

http://www.fpdf.org/